# Git extension for alert in Microsoft Visual studio for Backward Merge with your local branch from Global branch

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-extensions

I am working on Microsoft Visual studio and using GIT services for merge/push/pull with Visual Studio Online. Some times, a team working on same solutions and make some changes in files. so is there any extensions that notify to other person before doing anything we need back merge from global branch to local branch?

Comment: The "Incoming Changes" lens will show you that there are changes to the same files in another branch. Not really an alert, but if you're aware of them, they can be helpful. You do need to fetch these other branches though. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269218.aspx

Comment: @jessehouwing thank you

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t that extension for alert. You can refer to this workflow to do it:

1. Build an application (e.g. windows service)
2. Get commits through [Git Commits](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/commits) Rest API
3. Get commits via git command (e.g. git log)
4. Compare these records and send the notification (e.g. email) according to the compared result